# Call a stored procedure through a DB Link

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to call a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 over a DB Link but I am getting an error.

```
select * 
from openquery([DBLINK], 'EXEC Database.Schema123.ProcedureName123 ''2018-03-31'', ''7202''')
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "DBLINK" returned message
>   "Invalid procedure 'ProcedureName123'.
>   On line 0, column 0.  [parser-xyz] [Log ID: xyz] ".
>
> Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "DBLINK".

I can select from tables and views without an issue but procedures are failing.

Comment: if they are linked server, could you try to use four part query instead of open query?

Comment: Does the base call `EXEC Database.Schema123.ProcedureName123 '2018-03-31', '7202'` work when executed directly on `DBLINK`? Sounds obvious, but also the most obvious thing to miss.